# What would the Doctor be if he wasn't a Time Lord?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord

In the episode Listen, when the TARDIS lands on Gallifrey, Clara overhears a conversation between two people and one says:

> well he's not going to the academy , is he, that boy. He'll never make a time lord.

So I was wondering what would the Doctor be if he didn't become a Time Lord. I confess I'm not the most avid Doctor Who viewer and I haven't seen the earlier seasons so if this is a stupid question then I apologise. However, I would still like to know what a person from Gallifrey is called who isn't a Time Lord.

Comment: Probably just a mad man without a box.

Comment: The second answer in the question linked by Rogue Jedi provides some info.

Comment: This is a good question but you need to make it more specific. "*What would **The Doctor** have been if **he** hadn't become a Time Lord?"*

Comment: I love how the answer is contained in the question; even more so after the edit.